# How to have a save button with two different functionalities? like ADD and UPDATE in a save button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It's my first time to try angular in .NET with the use of local storage and I'm still trying to understand things. I hope someone will guide me here. Here are some snippet of the code I'm trying to do.

this is client.html:

```
<div class="box-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-ng-click="vm.save()"> Save</button>
</div>
```

this is clientService.js:

```
// Suppose to combine SAVE and EDIT but how?

function save(client) {
    var clients = [];
    if (localStorage.getItem('clients') != null)
        clients = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('clients'));

    clients.push(client);
    localStorage.setItem('clients', JSON.stringify(clients));
}

function edit(client) { 
    var clients = [];
    if (localStorage.getItem('clients') != null)
        clients = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('clients'));

    clients.forEach(function (client) {
        //compare the two ID's, if they are the same
        //Update 
    });
    //save
    localStorage.setItem('clients', JSON.stringify(clients));
}
```

this is client.js:

```
var vm = this;
vm.client = {
    id: '',
    firstname: '',
    lastname: '',
    age: ''
};
function edit() {
    clientService.edit(vm.client);
    getClients();
    clear();
}

function save() {
    clientService.save(vm.client);
    getClients();
    clear();
}
```

I expect to have a save button that can add a new data and update a data after selecting from the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are looking to update or save with same function try some thing like this

```
function edit(client) { 
    var clients = [];
     var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('clients'));
    if (data != null){
        clients = data;
        var position  = data.indexOf(client);

        /** checks if existing or not if then it will upadte same**/
        if(position != -1){
            clients[position] == client;
        }
        else{
             clients.push(client)
        }
    }
    else {
        /** push first item**/
        clients.push(client)
    }


    clients.forEach(function (client) {
        //compare the two ID's, if they are the same
        //Update 
    });
    //save
    localStorage.setItem('clients', JSON.stringify(clients));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, sir. But what if I want the 'save button' to be the 'edit' and 'add' button. How can I put the two functionalities in one function?

Comment: @Kloe this function  will allow edit and save both functionalities `if(position != -1){
            clients[position] == client;
        }` this part allow you to edit existing one

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator to check if there's a client upon submitting.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-ng-click="vm.client ? vm.edit() : vm.save()">
```